# How do I parse JSON with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm looking for a simple way to parse JSON, extract a value and write it into a database in Rails.

Specifically what I'm looking for, is a way to extract `shortUrl` from the JSON returned from the bit.ly API:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "errorMessage": "",
  "results":
  {
    "http://www.foo.com":
    {
       "hash": "e5TEd",
       "shortKeywordUrl": "",
       "shortUrl": "http://bit.ly/1a0p8G",
       "userHash": "1a0p8G"
    }
  },
  "statusCode": "OK"
}
```

And then take that shortUrl and write it into an ActiveRecord object associated with the long URL.

This is one of those things that I can think through entirely in concept and when I sit down to execute I realize I've got a lot to learn.

Answer (score 481):

These answers are a bit dated. Therefore I give you:

```
hash = JSON.parse string
```

Rails should automagically load the `json` module for you, so you *don't* need  to add `require 'json'`.

Answer (score 191):

Parsing JSON in Rails is quite straightforward:

```
parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(your_json_string)
```

Let's suppose, the object you want to associate the shortUrl with is a Site object, which has two attributes - short_url and long_url. Than, to get the shortUrl and associate it with  the appropriate Site object, you can do something like:

```
parsed_json["results"].each do |longUrl, convertedUrl|
  site = Site.find_by_long_url(longUrl)
  site.short_url = convertedUrl["shortUrl"]
  site.save
end
```

Comment: Newer version of Rails uses 'multi-json' gem, which uses the fastest json decoder installed in the Gemfile (e.g. oj). Therefore calling ActiveSupport::JSON will be fast if you have installed faster JSON parsers. (edit rejected therefore post as comment)

Comment: As for this comment `multi-json` is actually being dumped. There are benchmarks out there that show `multi-json` is actually slower than the built in `json` gem and other implementation of json parsers out there.

Answer (score 55):

This answer is quite old. pguardiario's got it.

One site to check out is [JSON implementation for Ruby](http://flori.github.com/json/). This site offers a gem you can install for a much faster C extension variant.

With the benchmarks given their [documentation page](http://flori.github.com/json/doc/index.html) they claim that it is **21.500x** faster than `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode`

The code would be the same as Milan Novota's answer with this gem, but the parsing would just be:

```
parsed_json = JSON(your_json_string)
```

Comment: Taken from the documentation, the parsing is now: parsed_json = JSON.parse(your_json_string)

Answer (score 25):

Here is an update for 2013.

#### Ruby

Ruby 1.9 has a default [JSON gem](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) with C extensions. You can use it with

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse ''{ "x": "y" }'
# => {"x"=>"y"}
```

The `parse!` variant can be used for *safe* sources. There are also other gems, which may be faster than the default implementation. Please refer to [multi_json](https://github.com/intridea/multi_json) for the list.

#### Rails

Modern versions of Rails use [multi_json](https://github.com/intridea/multi_json), a gem that automatically uses the fastest JSON gem available. Thus, the recommended way is to use

```
object = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode json_string
```

Please refer to [ActiveSupport::JSON](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) for more information. In particular, the important line in the method source is

```
data = MultiJson.load(json, options)
```

Then in your Gemfile, include the gems you want to use. For example,

```
group :production do
  gem 'oj'
end
```

Answer (score 11):

This can be done as below, just need to use `JSON.parse`, then you can traverse through it normally with indices.

```
#ideally not really needed, but in case if JSON.parse is not identifiable in your module  
require 'json'

#Assuming data from bitly api is stored in json_data here

json_data = '{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "errorMessage": "",
  "results":
  {
    "http://www.foo.com":
    {
       "hash": "e5TEd",
       "shortKeywordUrl": "",
       "shortUrl": "http://whateverurl",
       "userHash": "1a0p8G"
    }
  },
  "statusCode": "OK"
}'

final_data = JSON.parse(json_data)
puts final_data["results"]["http://www.foo.com"]["shortUrl"]
```

Answer (score 8):

Ruby's bundled [JSON](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) is capable of exhibiting a bit of magic on its own.

If you have a string containing JSON serialized data that you want to parse:

```
JSON[string_to_parse]
```

JSON will look at the parameter, see it's a String and try decoding it.

Similarly, if you have a hash or array you want serialized, use:

```
JSON[array_of_values]
```

Or:

```
JSON[hash_of_values]
```

And JSON will serialize it. You can also use the [`to_json`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#label-Generating+JSON) method if you want to avoid the visual similarity of the [`[]` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-c-5B-5D).

Here are some examples:

```
hash_of_values = {'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2}
array_of_values = [hash_of_values]

JSON[hash_of_values] 
# => "{\"foo\":1,\"bar\":2}"

JSON[array_of_values] 
# => "[{\"foo\":1,\"bar\":2}]"

string_to_parse = array_of_values.to_json
JSON[string_to_parse]
# => [{"foo"=>1, "bar"=>2}]
```

If you root around in JSON you might notice it's a subset of YAML, and, actually the YAML parser is what's handling JSON. You can do this too:

```
require 'yaml'

YAML.load(string_to_parse)
# => [{"foo"=>1, "bar"=>2}]
```

If your app is parsing both YAML and JSON, you can let YAML handle both flavors of serialized data.

Answer (score 7):

```
require 'json'
out=JSON.parse(input)
```

This will return a Hash

Answer (score 6):

```
require 'json'

hash = JSON.parse string
```

work with the hash and do what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

RUBY is case sensitive.

```
require 'json' # json must be lower case

JSON.parse(<json object>)
```

for example

```
JSON.parse(response.body) # JSON must be all upper-case
```

Answer (score 2):

The Oj gem (https://github.com/ohler55/oj) should work. It's simple and fast.

http://www.ohler.com/oj/#Simple_JSON_Writing_and_Parsing_Example

```
require 'oj'

h = { 'one' => 1, 'array' => [ true, false ] }
json = Oj.dump(h)

# json =
# {
#   "one":1,
#   "array":[
#     true,
#     false
#   ]
# }

h2 = Oj.load(json)
puts "Same? #{h == h2}"
# true
```

The Oj gem won't work for JRuby. For JRuby this (https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json) or this (https://github.com/clojure/data.json) may be good options.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do:

```
json = "{\"errorCode\":0,\"errorMessage\":\"\",\"results\":{\"http://www.foo.com\":{\"hash\":\"e5TEd\",\"shortKeywordUrl\":\"\",\"shortUrl\":\"http://b.i.t.ly/1a0p8G\",\"userHash\":\"1a0p8G\"}},\"statusCode\":\"OK\"}"

hash = JSON.parse(json)
results = hash[:results]
```

If you know the source url then you can use:

```
source_url = "http://www.foo.com".to_sym

results.fetch(source_url)[:shortUrl]
=> "http://b.i.t.ly/1a0p8G"
```

If you don't know the key for the source url you can do the following:

```
results.fetch(results.keys[0])[:shortUrl]
=> "http://b.i.t.ly/1a0p8G"
```

If you're not wanting to lookup keys using symbols, you can convert the keys in the hash to strings:

```
results = json[:results].stringify_keys

results.fetch(results.keys[0])["shortUrl"]
=> "http://b.i.t.ly/1a0p8G"
```

If you're concerned the JSON structure might change you could build a simple JSON Schema and validate the JSON before attempting to access keys. This would provide a guard.

NOTE: Had to mangle the bit.ly url because of posting rules.

Answer (score -3):

You can try something like this:

```
def details_to_json
{
  :id                    => self.id, 
  :credit_period_type    => self.credit_period_type,
  :credit_payment_period => self.credit_payment_period,

 }.to_json
end
```

Comment: parse json, not generate it!

Comment: Sorry about that, I was to quick on the trigger, lol. Use the Oj gem. - http://www.ohler.com/oj/#Simple_JSON_Writing_and_Parsing_Example