# How do I properly parse and display a JSON response from a variable in a Ruby controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to parse a response from the simplegeo API, I believe it is JSON format?  I am able to display the raw content on a page by referencing a variable in that page's controller.  Is there a simple way to clean up the response so it is not a jumbled mess?

I currently have this in the "view" of the particular page to display the response:

```
<%= @simple_geo_client %>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/rails-and-json-a-beginners-question

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you get the answer back as a JSON-string. You can parse this using

```
api_object = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(api_response)
```

This returns the data as a hash object. You can now access the attributes by simply doing api_object["my_attribute"].

Are you not using the official Ruby plugin though? You can find it [here](https://simplegeo.com/docs/tutorials/ruby).

Comment: So I have the following in my controller for the page I would like to display the parsed JSON response.  When attempting to load the page, I get an error.  "Cannot convert hash into string"  Any thoughts?



<p>
#class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  
#SimpleGeo::Client.set_credentials('token', 'secret')

#@simple_geo_client = SimpleGeo::Client.get_context(coordinates,coordinates)

#api_object = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(api_response)

#  end



#end
</p>