# Interfacing with a third-party API in Rails? ( Opening URLs and Parsing XML/JSON )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, json, api

I'm working on a Rails project which will need to interface with multiple third-party APIs.  I'm pretty new to Rails, and I've never done this before, so I'm lacking some basic information here.  Specifically, **What is the preferred Rails way of simply querying an external URL?**

In the PHP world, it was cURL.  You take whatever the resource URL is, throw cURL at it, and start processing the response, whether it be XML, JSON, etc.

**So, what's the cURL equivalent in Rails?**  While we're at it, **what is the preferred method of parsing XML and JSON responses?**  My instincts are to Google around for some Ruby gems to get the job done, but this is such a practical problem that I wouldn't be surprised if the Rails community had already worked out a tried-and-true solution to this kind of problem.

If it's of any contextual value, I plan to run these third-party API interactions as nightly cronjobs, probably all packaged up as custom rake tasks.

Thanks for sharing your expertise.

Comment: I found this presentation to be a helpful starting place in the past.  Note: there may be newer methods/gems today.  http://www.slideshare.net/pengwynn/json-and-the-apinauts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

for opening urls you can use `open-uri`

just

```
require 'open-uri'
file_handle = open("http://google.com/blah.xml")
```

to parse xml you can use Nokogiri

`$ gem install nokogiri`

```
document = Nokogiri::XML(file_handle)
document/"xpath/search"
```

very powerful library, can do all kinds of searching and modifying for both XML and HTML

same for html `Nokogiri::HTML`

there is also lots of JSOM support out there too

checkout [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) also Hpricot is good for XML/HTML

for JSON in rails

```
parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(your_json_string)

parsed_json["results"].each do |longUrl, convertedUrl|
  site = Site.find_by_long_url(longUrl)
  site.short_url = convertedUrl["shortUrl"]
  site.save
end
```

see this question:
[How do I parse JSON with Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 11):

In a perfect world, a gem already exists for the API you want to use, and you would just use that.  Otherwise, you have a few options:

- [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) might make sense for you depending on the complexity of the API you want to use.  For example, here's an old (and no longer functional) example of [using ActiveResource to connect to the Twitter API](http://functino.com/2010/02/twitter-api-with-rails/)
- [Net::Http](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html) is lower-level, but certainly does the trick
- [open-uri](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html) is a wrapper for net/http
- [Curb](http://curb.rubyforge.org/) uses libcurl to get things done

Parsing JSON is generally very straightforward.  For XML, as stated in another answer, Nokogiri is probably the way to go.