# How to read content of remote file in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json

here my file: http://example.com/test.txt

i have to read content of http://example.com/test.txt (a JSON string) and parse it in Ruby

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

Answer (score 25):

I would suggest using [open-uri](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html):

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
result = JSON.parse open('http://example.com/data.json').read
```

Comment: I have found that `OpenURI::HTTPError` gives much less information than the errors returned by `Net::HTTP`. It's been a while since I stopped using `OpenURI`, but if I recall correctly, it didn't even tell me the status code, so 404 was treated the same as 500.

Comment: @maurice, it does in fact tell you the HTTP status code, here's an example of a 404 wrapped by `OpenURI::HTTPError` - `404 Not Found`

Answer (score 6):

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://my.json.emitter/some/action')
json = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

`json` will contain the JSON string you fetched from `uri`.

Then read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails) StackOverflow post.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'

uri = URI.parse 'http://example.com/test.txt'
json =
  begin
    json_file = uri.open.read
  rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e
    puts "Encountered error pulling the file: #{e}"
  else
    JSON.parse json_file
  end
```

1. I specifically include `open-uri`, so that `open` is called from that module instead of attempting to call a private `open` from the `Kernel` module.
2. I intentionally parse the URL to avoid a security risk - https://rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Security/Open
3. Unlike some commenters pointed out above, `OpenURI` does indicate the HTTP status code of an error.