# Rails FTP OPEN CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ftp

I have the following code to connect my rails app to my FTP. This works great. However, I want to use open-uri to open the csv file so I can parse it. Any ideas how to do this? I think it's an easy thing to do but I'm missing something.

```
    require 'net/ftp'
    ftp = Net::FTP.new
    ftp.connect("xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",21)
    ftp.login("xxxxx","xxxx")
    ftp.chdir("/")
    ftp.passive = true
    puts ftp.list("TEST.csv")
```

Comment: Check if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149366/how-to-read-content-of-remote-file-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Have you tried `open('ftp://xxxxx:xxxx@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/TEST.csv')`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [#gettextfile](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-gettextfile).

A) Get the file to a local temporary file and read its content

```
# Creating a tmp file can be done differently as well.
# It may also be omitted, in which case `gettextfile`
# will create a file in the current directory.
Dir::Tmpname.create(['TEST', ['.csv']) do |file_name|
  ftp.gettextfile('TEST.csv', file_name)
  content = File.read(file_name)
end
```

B) Pass a block to `gettextfile` and get the content one line at a time

```
  content = ''
  ftp.gettextfile('TEST.csv') do |line|
    content << line
  end
```