# Serialize permissions (e.g. CanCan) with active_model_serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, activemodel, active-model-serializers

How do I serialize permissions with active_model_serializers? I don't have access to `current_user` or the `can?` method in models and serializers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First, to get access to the `current_user` in the serializer context, use the new scope feature:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  serialization_scope :current_user
end
```

In case you are instantiating serializers manually, be sure to pass the scope:

```
model.active_model_serializer.new(model, scope: serialization_scope)
```

Then inside the serializer, add custom methods to add your own authorization pseudo-attributes, using `scope` (the current user) to determine permissions.

If you are using CanCan, you can instantiate your Ability class to access the `can?` method:

```
attributes :can_update, :can_delete

def can_update
  # `scope` is current_user
  Ability.new(scope).can?(:update, object)
end

def can_delete
  Ability.new(scope).can?(:delete, object)
end
```

Comment: I don't understand -- did you answer your own question right away?

Comment: Yes, I did – see [this article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). I wanted this piece of knowledge preserved, but found it too trivial/specialized to post on my blog, so I posted it here, Q&A style.

Comment: @JoLiss As an alternative to the "super.merge" style, you can say `attributes :can_update, :can_delete` and then define can_update and can_delete as methods in the serializer. Either works, though.

Comment: You can also delegate the `can?` method to your model for even better readability — see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3293522/797639.

Answer (score 3):

We created a gem that provides this functionality: https://github.com/GroupTalent/active_model_serializers-cancan

Answer (score 2):

I think you can pass anything you want to `serialization_scope` so I simply pass the Ability.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 ...
 serialization_scope :current_ability

 def current_ability
   @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user)
 end

end


class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :content, :created_at, :can_update

  def can_update
    scope.can?(:update, object)
  end

end
```

I can't do otherwise since my abilities are actually based on two variables (not in the example above).
If you still need access to current_user you can simply set an instance variable on Ability.