# Serialize Cancan permissions to emberjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ember.js

I was wondering if any one knows how to serialize CanCan permissions to emberjs. I saw this StackOverflow Q &A by Jo_Liss where she explained how to **[Serialize permissions (e.g. CanCan) with active_model_serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660179/serialize-permissions-e-g-cancan-with-active-model-serializers)**, but stopped at that level. Also **[this article linked to here, talks on how to check permission on the emberjs side](http://livsey.org/blog/2012/10/16/writing-a-helper-to-check-permissions-in-ember-dot-js/)**, but nothing how on how to serialize the permission from the backend into emberjs.

I hope to have 3 kinds of user roles that is 'admin', 'author', 'user' and will want to use CanCan permissions on emberjs to control what they can access once they are in the logged-in route.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the UserSerializer to serialize the users CanCan Ability:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email, :ability

  def ability
    Ability.new(self).as_json
  end
end
```

That will return something like:

```
user: {
  id: 1,
  name: "xxx",
  email: "xxx",
  ability: rules: [
    {
      match_all: false,
      base_behavior: false,
      actions: [
        "edit"
      ],
      subjects: [
        "user"
      ],
      conditions: { },
      block: null
    },
    {
      match_all: false,
      base_behavior: true,
      actions: [
        "read"
      ],
      subjects: [
        "user"
      ],
      conditions: { },
      block: null
    }
  ]
}
```

You would need to implement some sort of can? and cannot? helper in javascript to process the abilities.

Hope that helps.

Comment: **One possible way to define some sort of 'can' or  'canRead' property to check user authorization** can be seen here, just to close the loop
**http://jsfiddle.net/machty/Wjtcj/31/** and **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372214/emberjs-1-x-pre-ember-router-and-ember-computed-issues/13393756#comment18297460_13393756**