# Devise + CanCan in Ember.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ember.js, cancan

Is there a non-trivial example / tutorial that implements Devise + CanCan in an Ember.js + Ember-data + Rails app?

Answer (score 2):

There is not. FWIW a simple approach for ember/rails apps is to use rails primarily as API and assume user has been authenticated externally. So you can use standard rails/devise login/signup pages, then send authenticated users to ember app. Then ember app calls api in context of an authenticated user and your api uses CanCan to determine role and return appropriate data. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I used [this site](http://say26.com/using-rails-devise-with-ember-js) which has been pointed out by a few people working with ember as a reasonable way of doing things. It is more or less what @Michael Grassotti is explaining above.

There are a lot of blogs about all kind of changes you have to make on Devise before it would work, but they are quite old, I had Devise working nicely very quick, without any changes. Be sure to make a User serializer (active_record_serializers) which is skipped in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

The proper answer to this question is still "no", but there are some decent resources from which you may be able to construct your own:

- The [in depth and up to date tutorial](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth-rails-demo/wiki) for heartsentwined's [ember-auth-rails-demo](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth-rails-demo), which uses devise with his [ember-auth-rails](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth-rails) gem and [ember-auth](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth) library.
- Richard Livsey's [fantastic blog post](http://livsey.org/blog/2012/10/16/writing-a-helper-to-check-permissions-in-ember-dot-js/) about adding a `#can` helper to ember.
- Delwyn's [stackoverflow sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13332408/1546887) for serializing CanCan abilities so you can reference them on the client side. Still up to you to get them there and use them though.