# Store JSON at URL in Rails array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm building a Facebook canvas app in Rails, and I'm looking to display all of the photos in a given photo album. I can generate the URL that will take me to a page with a `JSON` feed of the data associated with those photos, but I'm not clear on how to capture that information and store it in an array within Rails. If anyone could help me I'd appreciate it!

The request I'm making is to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/'+album["id"].to_s+'/photos/?fields=source&access_token='+@token["oauth_token"]
```

Where `album['id']` and `@token[oauth_token]` are user specific.

Comment: Usually you capture the data into a model you've created. Is there something exotic here you're not describing?

Comment: Nothing exotic - all I'm doing is grabbing the cover images of each of the user's albums with the intention that, when the user clicks the image, they'd be taken to another page with all of the images from that album present. I just don't have a lot of experience with JSON, especially not within Rails.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Could you please update how your request will be so that I can write the logic to parse the JSON and store data into the database?

Comment: @soundar I've just updated, is that what you need?

Comment: @sowasred2012 shall we continue this in chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a JSON string `var_json_string`, you can convert it to a Hash by doing:

```
JSON.parse(var_json_string)
```

Comment: Cheers, the problem I was having was with using the net/http gem, I couldn't catch the response from that address, but I've found HTTParty, and that solved my first issue. Your answer then helped with the rest!