# using Json file data to render a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I know that similar questions have been posted in this regard. but i need a derivative of these answers because i'm new to RoR.
i have a json file with some data in it with which i want to perform the following:

1. I want to use the content,
2. Render it as a Table from the view.

The following is the content of the json file

```
[
  {
    "id": "A",
    "description": "a_description_one"
    "value": some_alphanumeric_string
  },
  {
    "id": "B",
    "description": "b_description_one"
    "value": some_alphanumeric_string
  },
  {
    "id": "C",
    "description": "c_description_one"
    "value": some_alphanumeric_string
  }
]
```

I get the content of this file in my controller in the below code:

```
def index
@data = File.read(Rails.root.join("public", "newjson.json"))
render :json => @data
end
```

But when i try to use this JSON object @data in the view inside a view, i either get the downloadable json file or the error.i'm not sure of how to render the @data object as a Table in the view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
render :json => @data
```

renders your @data into json and returns it. delete this line and try to parse your json file correctly (see [how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails)) and then modify your view-file as needed.