# Updating Rails Model with JSON data Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to update a rails model but I am facing some errors with the data handling even though the ajax request does go through.

The parameters being sent appears as shown below:

```
Parameters: {"{\"slot_allocation\":{\"timeslot_id\":\"3\",\"subject_id\":\"3\",\"slot_allocation_id\":\"1\",\"group_index\
":\"Group 2\",\"lesson_type\":\"Tutorial\"}}"=>nil, "id"=>"1"}
  SlotAllocation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "slot_allocations".* FROM "slot_allocations" WHERE "slot_allocations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1
  [["id", "1"]]
```

Whereas a normal update does:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yBib4ftNdB/r25uZuGnqEZI+r9dulVhyoce8nWBfcBQ=", "slot_allocation"=>{"slot_
allocation_id"=>"1", "lesson_type"=>"Lecture", "group_index"=>"Group 1", "timeslot_id"=>"1", "subject_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"
Update Slot allocation", "id"=>"1"}
  SlotAllocation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "slot_allocations".* FROM "slot_allocations" WHERE "slot_allocations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1
  [["id", "1"]]
```

I am not sure where I have gone wrong being new to Rails and JSON.

I have tried out solutions posted by [How do I parse JSON with Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails). But after changing my codes the requests does not get sent out. I have also tried changing the data being sent by following certain examples but it didn't work out as well.

I would appreciate advice on what I could do to solve this error.

The following are the relevant codes:

My Ajax request:

```
var url = 'slot_allocations/'+alloc_id;

var dataToServer = {"slot_allocation":{"timeslot_id":timeslot, "subject_id":subject,"slot_allocation_id":alloc_id, "group_index":"Group 2", "lesson_type":"Tutorial"}}

  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: url, 
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToServer) 
    });
```

My controller update action:

```
  def update
    @slot_allocation = SlotAllocation.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
     if @slot_allocation.update_attributes(params[:slot_allocation])
        format.html { redirect_to @slot_allocation, notice: 'Slot allocation was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok}
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @slot_allocation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js  { render :js => @slot_allocation.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I would appreciate any advice on where I might have gone wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you converting the data to JSON when calling `$.ajax` ? `update_attributes` expects a Hash where you pass a `nil` value.

Comment: Hi, I am inexperience with these and thought that converting the data to JSON was the way to go. Previously I tried displaying data on my client side with server data using json and it worked so I thought it might work the other way as well. How would you suggest I approach this otherwise?

Comment: See my answer below for the standard/RESTful/Rails way of sending parameters to the controller.

Comment: Saw it, thank you once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update_attributes` expects a Hash. By converting the data you send to the server to JSON,  params contains a JSON string instead. You should call the controller with standard POST data:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  url: url, 
  dataType: "json",
  data: dataToServer
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I gathered that I would need to stringify it from some examples without understanding why. This worked.