# How to pass json object to controller using ajax?

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a json object.I want to create a new student by passing this value.How to pass the value of that object to controller using ajax in ruby on rails?
This is the code i used for passing the object.

```
self.save = function() {
       var dataToSave = {
                    Name: self.firstName(),
                    _age: self.Age()
                 }
       alert(JSON.stringify(dataToSave))
         $.ajax({
        url: '/students/new',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'PUT',
        data: {total_changes: JSON.stringify(dataToSave)},
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Successful");
          },
          failure: function() {
            alert("Unsuccessful");
          }
        });
       // TODO send request
  };

}
```

i
There is some error in terminal. It shows

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"new", "total_changes"=>"{\"Name\":\"hu\",\"_age\":\"7\"}"}
```

id is taken as new.Rake routes

```
[nithinv@ast297 jquery_country]$ rake routes
     students GET    /students(.:format)          students#index
              POST   /students(.:format)          students#create
  new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)      students#new
 edit_student GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format) students#edit
      student GET    /students/:id(.:format)      students#show
              PUT    /students/:id(.:format)      students#update
              DELETE /students/:id(.:format)      students#destroy
```

controller is

```
def new
    @student = Student.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @student }
    end
  end
```

How can i go to create function in the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this url:

```
 alert(JSON.stringify(dataToSave))
     $.ajax({
    url: '/students',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: {total_changes: JSON.stringify(dataToSave)},
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Successful");
      },
      failure: function() {
        alert("Unsuccessful");
      }
    });
```

Change url to /students

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what you ask it to do - converts JSON object into a valid string representation.

Now you need to parse this JSON string:

[How do I parse JSON with Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your routes.rb is having false routing and that is why you are getting `id` as `new`.

It should be:

**routes.rb**

```
resources "students" 

match "/students/new" => "students#new"
```

This will call `new` action in your `students` controller. So it depends that what code your `new` action has in the `students` controller.

The rest of your code seems to be right. But if you still get error than show the error message that you are getting and also the `new` action code further.

Comment: Yes it is correct and will call the new action of students controller.

Comment: I edited my code with your suggestion but still the terminal shows  Parameters: {"id"=>"new", "total_changes"=>"{\"Name\":\"yut\",\"_age\":\"6\"}"}
id= 'new'....

Comment: also there was an error like this ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Student with id=new):

Comment: show your routes for students by running `rake routes |grep students`

Comment: [nithinv@ast297 jquery_country]$ rake routes

     students GET    /students(.:format)          students#index

              POST   /students(.:format)          students#create

  new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)      students#new

 edit_student GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format) students#edit

      student GET    /students/:id(.:format)      students#show

              PUT    /students/:id(.:format)      students#update

              DELETE /students/:id(.:format)      students#destroy

Comment: I added the new action of students controller