# Format a quoted array string into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json, string

I have data like:

```
"[{\"workstationName\":\"Test Workstation Id 123\"},{\"workstationName\":\"Alex's Workstation\"}]"
```

I want it to simply be:

```
[{"workstationName":"Test Workstation Id 123"},{"workstationName":"Alex's Workstation"}]
```

I should know this. I tried `a.to_ary`, but no good. Any straight-forward way to process this? Thanks.

Comment: `JSON.parse(your_string)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON with Ruby on Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Your expected result is not valid Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How is this ?

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

JSON.parse("[{\"workstationName\":\"Test Workstation Id 123\"},{\"workstationName\":\"Alex's Workstation\"}]")
# => [{"workstationName"=>"Test Workstation Id 123"},
#     {"workstationName"=>"Alex's Workstation"}]

YAML.load("[{\"workstationName\":\"Test Workstation Id 123\"},{\"workstationName\":\"Alex's Workstation\"}]")
# => [{"workstationName"=>"Test Workstation Id 123"},
#     {"workstationName"=>"Alex's Workstation"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` is what you're looking for