# How to access the properties of returned json object? (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, json, http, angularjs

I'm trying to do an api call to facebook (using angularJs.
Here's my code (taken from the service):

```
fbTest: function (name) {
    resource = $resource('http://graph.facebook.com/:id?fields=id,name,picture', { id: '@id' });
    return resource.get({ id: name });
}
```

It returns the data just fine: (inspected with Fiddler)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
ETag: "c49e5dcad5a864ff2e16bb3af547231f725c05e7"
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
X-FB-Rev: 1002313
X-FB-Debug: tMeW4nnfiRBj6VK+QRtbe0YdaGfQfkXcaWL4VzXTXxw=
Date: Mon, 11 Nov 2013 16:53:29 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 241

{
   "id": "Data",
   "name": "Data",
   "picture": {
      "data": {
         "url": "Data",
         "is_silhouette": false
      }
   }
}
```

However how can I access the properties?
I tried writing .name but that doesn't return anything.

Comment: See this article:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @NickM
I looked at it but I don't get what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the result of the get isn't ready when you return the function. You are returning a `promise`.

Try binding the `$resource.get` to some attribute in your `$scope` and, when ready, it will be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) is a little unclear to me, but it seems like some of the exposed methods such as `.get` execute asynchronously.  What this means is that the return value from `.get` may not actually be returning the data from HTTP.

Instead, you need to do something like:

```
resource.get({ id: name }, function (data) {
    // do something with data.name, etc.
});
```