# How do I generate and parse JSON in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, json, dictionary

I need to create and parse(on view side) a JSON in Ruby.

In my case, JSON must contain string value as a key, and an array of strings as its value.

Something like this...

```
JSON:
key1 -> {a,b,c}
key2 -> {d,e,f}
```

My question:
1.) How can we do this? Does Ruby have a JSON parsing library, or do I have to implement it myself?

2.) I am coming from the Java domain. IN java, we have map, hash map, hasmap, listmap, etc. Do we have same kind of facility in Ruby?

Comment: please take Guide from this : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON you are describing will look like this when you create it:

```
{ "key1": ["a", "b", "c"], "key2": ["d", "e", "f"] }
```

You can create this automatically in Ruby by using the JSON library and calling `#to_json` on a Ruby hash:

```
require 'json'
data_hash = { key1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], key2: ['d', 'e', 'f'] }
json_data_string = data_hash.to_json
```

You can parse it using the same JSON library:

```
require 'json'
JSON::parse(json_data_string)
```

Have a look at the [JSON library documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html).

Comment: what abt map / hashmap ? can we provide some link for that?

Comment: +1 for the documentation link...