# Don't understand how to parse json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing, ruby-on-rails-4, irb

```
data = {
  "CEO": "William Hummel",
  "CFO": "Carla Work"
  }
```

I'm trying to parse the json data above with `JSON.parse(data)` in IRC, but it won't work.

I'm getting the following error: "SyntaxError: (irb):44: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC"

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that most upvoted answer I'm trying to use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11430924/3205492

Comment: Well then, I believe you want data to look like `data = '{...}'` Parse is looking for a string, and you are passing a dict.

Comment: unlike javascript, json is not first class citizen of Ruby. json data is represented as a string. You can use %q() notation for multiline strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON.parse takes a string argument. You are trying to construct a Hash using JSON syntax. Use a string instead:

```
data = '{"CEO": "William Hummel", "CFO": "Carla Work"}'
JSON.parse(data)
```

Comment: Literally as I was typing. This should fix the issue.