# QPX Express API obj not parsing properly when passed to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I've been trying for quite some time now to figure out why the JSON object I'm passing through AJAX to Rails with Typhoeus isn't working properly. Apologies if this is a newb question but I'm relatively new to web dev.

I've spent all day looking at docs, googling, and on SO but I haven't been able to figure out much for some reason.

I'm trying to pass a request to Google's QPX Express API for flight search and the docs say to send a JSON obj in the following format:

```
{
  "request": {
    "passengers": {
      "kind": "qpxexpress#passengerCounts",
      "adultCount": 1,
      "childCount": 0,
      "infantInLapCount": 0,
      "infantInSeatCount": 0,
      "seniorCount": 0
    },
    "slice": [
      {
        "kind": "qpxexpress#sliceInput",
        "origin": "SFO",
        "destination": "HNL",
        "date": "2015-04-03",
        "maxStops": 0,
        "maxConnectionDuration": 0,
        "preferredCabin": "COACH",
        "permittedDepartureTime": {
          "kind": "qpxexpress#timeOfDayRange",
          "earliestTime": "00:00",
          "latestTime": "11:59"
        },
        "permittedCarrier": [
          "VX",
          "UA"
        ],
        "alliance": "",
        "prohibitedCarrier": [
          ""
        ]
      }
    ],
    "maxPrice": "USD1000.00",
    "saleCountry": "US",
    "refundable": false,
    "solutions": 1
  }
}
```

I have this stored a variable which is referenced in the AJAX request below as 'reqBody':

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/search',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  method: 'POST',
  // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: JSON.stringify(reqBody),
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

And this is call goes to the rails controller shown here, using Typhoeus to process the request/response:

```
reqBody = params[:request]
flightRequest = Typhoeus::Request.new(
  "https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=APIKEY",
  method: :post,
  headers: {'Content-Type'=> "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
  body: reqBody,
)
flightRequest.run
@results = JSON.parse(flightRequest.response.body)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: {
    :results => @results
    }
  }
end
```

This ends up being the response I get back:

```
{"results":{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"parseError","message":"Parse Error"}],"code":400,"message":"Parse Error"}}}
```

And this is what I get when I look at the obj in pry:

```
=> {"passengers"=>
  {"kind"=>"qpxexpress#passengerCounts",
   "adultCount"=>1,
   "childCount"=>0,
   "infantInLapCount"=>0,
   "infantInSeatCount"=>0,
   "seniorCount"=>0},
 "slice"=>
  [{"kind"=>"qpxexpress#sliceInput",
    "origin"=>"SFO",
    "destination"=>"HNL",
    "date"=>"2015-04-03",
    "maxStops"=>0,
    "maxConnectionDuration"=>0,
    "preferredCabin"=>"COACH",
    "permittedDepartureTime"=>
     {"kind"=>"qpxexpress#timeOfDayRange", "earliestTime"=>"00:00", "latestTime"=>"11:59"},
    "permittedCarrier"=>["VX", "UA"],
    "alliance"=>"",
    "prohibitedCarrier"=>[""]}],
 "maxPrice"=>"USD1000.00",
 "saleCountry"=>"US",
 "refundable"=>false,
 "solutions"=>1}
```

What's going on here? Shouldn't the object be a string since I stringified it in the AJAX request? Is this why there's a parsing error when I send the object to the QPX Express API?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, 
did you require 'json' in your controller?

The other thing you could try is the variant of parse

parse! which can be used for safe *safe* sources.

here is a link!

[How do I parse JSON with Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails?rq=1)

good luck