# How to parse incoming JSON from my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am JSON posting the following JSON to my controller:

```
{"user_id": 234324, "user_action": 2, "updated_email": "asdf@asdf.com" }
```

In my controller I can see the JSON is correctly POSTED but I am not sure how to access it:

```
def update_email
  puts request.body.read.html_safe

  user_id = params[:user_id]
  user = User.find(user_id)
end
```

I am testing this in my controller_spec and currently it is throwing an exception and is showing the id is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate - see: [How do I parse JSON with Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails)

I'm not sure how you're passing the JSON. Is it part of the POST params? In the header? Or something else. My guess is that you're either passing it as a param or should do so: e.g. myJson = {"user_id": 234324, "user_action": 2, "updated_email": "asdf@asdf.com" }

As far as parsing it goes, you should be able to use the built-in JSON class for this.

```
hash = JSON.parse params["myJson"]
```

Comment: I'm just confused, when you post the json ```{"user_id": 234324, "user_action": 2, "updated_email": "asdf@asdf.com" }``` how can you access it using params["myJson"] ?  there is no myJson in the JSON?? Is myJson just arbitrary?

Comment: It's meant to represent however you're passing the information. Are you sending this JSON through an AJAX call as a param? What are you referring to by saying you're "JSON posting?" Could you add the code that's sending the POST to the controller - that may help.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing it with `params` is the right way.

In your case:

```
params["user_id"] # => 234324
```

`request.body.read` shouldn't be used in real world, just for debugging, as action_dispatch does all the dispatch for you (like parse JSON or form data).

Note: you need to have the correct headers set, to let rails know that you're passing JSON.