# How to get POST request from API with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, post, webhooks

I got POST request from API. I checked content-type, it's x-www-form-urlencoded, but body request also contains JSON. How can I parse from JSON in hash?

Parameters of request in console: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg55F.png) || `Parameters: {"vpbx_api_key"=>"etxojfklr6nue6tl627pn5sdi0koov7t", "sign"=>"ad0c49034c8d83a7d7f1b433afc2ed5a9aa08d933dba3724062aed0c3d1a79bb", "json"=>"{\"entry_id\":\"MjYyNjQ2NzM1Njo0Mg==\",\"call_id\":\"MToxMDAxNDAzOTo0Mjo4Mjc2NzEzMzk=\",\"timestamp\":1485939839,\"seq\":2,\"call_state\":\"Disconnected\",\"location\":\"abonent\",\"from\":{\"number\":\"79268220697\",\"taken_from_call_id\":\"MToxMDAxNDAzOTo0Mjo4Mjc2NzEwOTA6MQ==\"},\"to\":{\"extension\":\"2\",\"number\":\"79154612023\",\"line_number\":\"74953749768\"},\"disconnect_reason\":1100}"}`

Comment: Did you check the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the form encoded that way, you will have the parameters in the params collection. That means you could be parsing that JSON doing something as:

```
def my_method_to_process_the_post
    parsed = JSON.parse params[:json]
end
```

'json' is the key for the json that you are receiving in the payload.

For historical evolution of JSON parsing you may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails) thread.