# From Ember to JSON API with Rails 5 and active_model_serializers - how to parse params hash in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers, json-api

I followed the settings described in [active_model_serializers guide](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/integrations/ember-and-json-api.md) to couple a Rails 5 API with Ember 3 app.
In Rails `ShopLanguagesController`, I modified `shop_language_params` method as described in the above guide:

```
private

  def shop_language_params
    #params.require(:shop_language).permit(:shop_id, :language_id, :modified_by)
    ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(params, only: [:shop_id, :language_id, :modified_by] )
  end
```

Here is what I get when I post the following data from Ember app (seen in Rails log console):

```
Started POST "/shops/613/languages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-09 16:53:05 +0200
Processing by ShopLanguagesController#create as JSONAPI
  Parameters: {"data"=>{"attributes"=>{"modified_by"=>"Z28SCAMB"}, "relationships"=>{"shop"=>{"data"=>{"type"=>"shops", "id"=>"613"}}, "language"=>{"data"=>{"type"=>"languages", "id"=>"374"}}}, "type"=>"shop-languages"}, "shop_id"=>"613"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["username", "Z28SCAMB"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Shop Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 613], ["LIMIT", 1]]
++++ params: {:modified_by=>"Z28SCAMB"}
```

The posted data seems to be correct.
How to extract the needed parameters (for example, `language_id`) from this JSON ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON with Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826727/how-do-i-parse-json-with-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Parsing JSON in Rails is quite straightforward:

```
parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(your_json_string)
```

Let's suppose, the object you want to associate the shortUrl with is a Site object, which has two attributes - short_url and long_url. Than, to get the shortUrl and associate it with  the appropriate Site object, you can do something like:

```
parsed_json["results"].each do |longUrl, convertedUrl|
  site = Site.find_by_long_url(longUrl)
  site.short_url = convertedUrl["shortUrl"]
  site.save
end
```

Comment: Thank you, Mauricio for the response. What confuses me the most is the lack of examples and documentation on the Rails side. I believed that active_model_serializers gem will be smart enough to do all this hard parsing. If not it has not so much utility in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to modify the private `shop_language_params` method in `ShopLanguagesController` as follows:

```
def shop_language_params
    ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(params, only: [:shop, :language, :modified_by] )
end
```

As you see, I permit not foreign keys values for shop and language (`shop_id` and `language_id`) but the objects themselves: `:shop` and `:language`. Now you have `shop_id` and `language_id` values available in `params` hash as usually.

And, of course, you should call `shop_language_params` everywhere in the controller where you need do pass the `shop_language` params.
Example where I find a language in the same controller:

```
private 

def find_language
    @language = Language.find_by!(id: shop_language_params[:language_id])
end
```